# SWIG TypeError: in method 'B_create', argument 1 of type 'A const &'

Tags: python, c++, swig, typemaps

Let's say I have a class `A` and class `B` such that class `B` has a method that looks like:

```cpp
B* create(const A& a, int c){...}
```

an acceptable type of `A` is also a string, for example, I can call:

```cpp
B::create("hello", 5);
```

and it'll be accepted in the C++ interface and work fine!

My problem here is that while wrapping class `B` with SWIG I want to be able to call `create` in Python just like in the c++ interface, for example:

```py
B.create('hello', 5)
```

but for that I think I need a typemap, because right now I'm getting an error that says:

`TypeError: in method 'B_create', argument 1 of type 'A const &'`

How can I typemap it correctly?
Tried:

`%typemap(in) const A& = const char*;`

But It's not working (I assume because I don't really get the documentation about typemapping)

I found this StackOverflow thread: [How to use Swig to treat a void * function parameter as Python string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686400/how-to-use-swig-to-treat-a-void-function-parameter-as-python-string) and tried it myself:
`%typemap(in) const A& = char*;` but it gives me  a segmentation fault.